# Was Elon Musk financially supported by his parents in college and his business or is he self-made?

Tags: finance, elon-musk

The [Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/space/elon-musk-made-money-rich-b2212599.html) writes:

> As a result of this, the teenage Elon Musk once walked the streets of
> New York with emeralds in his pocket. His father said: “We were very
> wealthy. We had so much money at times we couldn’t even close our
> safe,” adding that one person would have to hold the money in place
> with another closing the door. “And then there’d still be all these
> notes sticking out and we’d sort of pull them out and put them in our
> pockets.”

Elon Musk writes on [X](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1211054942192119808):

> He didn’t own an emerald mine & I worked my way through college, ending up ~$100k in student debt. I couldn’t even afford a 2nd PC at Zip2, so programmed at night & website only worked during day. Where is this bs coming from?

What's the truth? Was Elon Musk bankrolled by his father or did he work his way through college with student debt?

Comment: So his father was so rich he couldn't afford a large enough safe to put it?

Comment: @WeatherVane Better question someone that rich was so stupid as to put money in a safe rather then a bank or investing it?  And didn't care to keep track of his money well enough to know who walked off with how much money or that he could just exchange mall bills for big.  The whole concept of a safe stuffed full of excess money is absurd.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 2022, [Snopes did an investigation](https://www.snopes.com/news/2022/11/17/elon-musk-emerald-mine/) - rather thorough for them - looking at the variety of claims and the evidence.

They found some stories about Errol Musk buying a part share in an emerald mine in the mid-80s (bought after selling his share of a plane in Zambia). Errol Musk claims the scheme collapsed about six years later in the late 1980s.

Snopes quotes Elon Musk and Errol Musk extensively, and concludes:

> A story about Musk's father once owning an emerald mine evolved into a larger rumor that had no evidence to support its central claim.

That is, there is no evidence that Elon Musk's initial wealth was seeded in a large part by a rich father who made a fortune from emeralds. (A smaller investment is noted by Elon Musk.)

Comment: You spoke to the emerald mind,  but that is only half the question.   Anyone rich enough to be sellng planes and buying emeralds mines - even if temporarily - seems like they would be rich enough to pay for musk's college even if that money wasn't due to emeralds.  Is there any evidence that musk really did end up having to pay off a  100K student loan?

Comment: @dsollen: We have statements from Elon Musk saying he paid his own way, and we have Snopes saying there is no evidence to support that Errol Musk paid for it.

Comment: My quick scanning of the snoopes article shows it discuss the emerald mine, but not rather or not musk paid his way through college.  It's possible I missed it but then again you should have a summary in your answer that touches on such things if I have missed it and your answer says nothing about it.  The question asked was "Was Elon Musk bankrolled by his father or did he work his way through college with student debt?" you gave a detailed answer to rather or not his father owned an emerald mine and never directly answered the actual question OP asked.

Comment: This also stinks of some sort of anti-musk vendetta. The mines in South Africa are mostly done by multinational corporations. Any South African is free to open an online share trading account at any bank and buy shares in any mining company. Doing so technically making you own a small part of a mine.

Comment: IDK why people would think owning shares of URA Holdings the company that bought the rights to Gravelotte Emerald mine in 2023 would be so extraordinary.

Comment: Well, the wealth of Elon Musk's father depends on who or what you compare it to. He did go to Waterkloof House Preparatory School which is a rather high-brow school and by no means the type of education poverty-stricken parents provide their kids

Comment: Here is what his school currently asks for tuition, just to put it in perspective... https://www.whpsschool.com/wp-content/uploads/WHPS-Fee-Information_2023.pdf - Decide if being able to pay that makes a person officially rich.

Comment: @dsollen: The question asks whether Elon Musk was self-made or supported by his family in college and business. The article says "Beyond [evidence of a stake in an Emerald mine] we were unable to find any evidence that showed money generated from his father's involvement in the mine helped Elon build his wealth in North America." I summarised that in the answer. This isn't a smoking gun student loan receipt or a detailed breakdown of the finances of Zip2. It is a flat denial by Elon Musk and a lack of evidence to support the claim.

Comment: @NeilMeyer: (1) Please be clear where the anti-Musk vendetta is. I assume you are not talking about my answer. (2) The claim may be true or false, even if it is an anti-Musk vendatta. (3) The idea that Errol Musk just had a few shares in a publicly-owned mine appears to be a straw-man. Who is saying that was the situation?

Comment: @Oddthinking I was generally referring to the complete hysteria involving the man. Also, that is the only way to 'own' a mine in SA.

Comment: @Oddthinking I found this article is it worth adding? - https://www.news24.com/fin24/companies/musks-dad-the-emerald-mine-and-the-blacks-truth-revealed-in-new-biography-20230915